# percent correct for N trials at each intensity in R

Tags: r, percentage

I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the percentage correct for each different number in V3. V4 shows whether the answer was correct or not. V2 is the block number.

```
V2 V3 V4 

1  4  1      
1 10  1  
1  4  0  
1  4  1  
1 10  0  
2  8  1
2  8  0
```

Thank you for all your help. I'm new to R and have been googling this problem for hours!

Comment: Show us an example of what you would like the result to be. Also, when you are giving us example data (which is good) use `dput(df)` where `df` is your `data.frame` so that we can just cut and paste into our browsers.

Comment: In the example given percentage correct for 4 would be 66.66%, for 10 it would be 50% and for 8 50% - How would I get R to generate those numbers for me? Also, thanks for the advice. Will remember next time.

Comment: So in that case the answer below works. It seems that `V2` isn't needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Calling your data frame `DF`:

```
tapply(DF$V4 * 100, DF$V3, mean)
```

Will give you the percentage correct for each unique number in `V3`.

Answer (score 0):

using data.table might be helpful here

```
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(DF, key="V2")
mydt[, mean(V4), by=V3]
```

Results:

```
   V3        V1
1:  4 0.6666667
2: 10 0.5000000
3:  8 0.5000000
```

---

**Then if you want to clean it up aesthetically:**

```
# you can format it nicely using round
mydt[, round(100*mean(V4),2), by=V3]

#      V3    V1
#   1:  4 66.67
#   2: 10 50.00
#   3:  8 50.00


# you can give the new column a name (wrap it all in a list)
mydt[, list("Percent" = round(100*mean(V4),2)), by=V3]

#     V3   Percent
#   1:  4    66.67
#   2: 10    50.00
#   3:  8    50.00
```